# Does xdotool not work with any Windows program?

Tags: wine, xdotool

On Lubuntu 18.04, I have [a Windows GUI program](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) running under wine-3.0.2, and its process id is 20709.

When I run:

```
xdotool search --pid 20709
```

it doesn't output anything. I was expecting its window id.

```
$ xdotool search --pid 20709 windowraise
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname
$ xdotool search --pid 20709 windowactivate
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname
```

Doesn't raise its window to the front either.
Does xdotool not work with any Windows program?

How can I bring the window of a Windows/wine program to the front, using xdotool or some other tool, given its pid?

Thanks.

originated from https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458895/674

---

**Update:**

I ran the Windows program via a script `PDFXCview`,

```
PDFXCview  my.pdf &
```

The script's content is

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                      
/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine "/path/to/PDFXCview.exe" "$@"
```

If I run the Windows program directly

```
/path/to/PDFXCview.exe my.pdf &
```

then the above problem doesn't happen.

So the problem happens only when I run the Windows program via my script. I was wondering why and how I can still use my script to run the Windows program but without the above problem with xdotool?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `xdotool search --pid 20709 windowraise`. Been a while, though, so not sure if the order of arguments is proper

Comment: Strange; I cannot replicate this.
Please humor me and ensure you're not using Wayland...

Comment: Whatever is used by Lubuntu 18.04.@Nonny  can you reply with how you succeed?

Comment: Can you check using [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325972/199500)?

Comment: X11 @Nonny  can you reply with how you succeed?

Comment: Sure. I installed and ran it in wine, then did `ps -e | grep -i pdf` which returned `1844 pts/2    00:00:01 PDFXCview.exe`. Then I did `xdotool search --pid 1844` and got
`121634820
121634819
121634821
121634823
121634824
121634825
121634826
121634827
121634828
121634829
121634830
121634831
121634833
121634834
121634835
121634836
121634822`

Comment: Can you show the command which  runs the Windows program? @NonnyMoose Mine is `wine PDFXCview.exe my.pdf`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80791/discussion-between-nonny-moose-and-tim).

Comment: You are right. The problem happens only when I run the program by a wrapper shell script. See my update @Nonny.

Comment: Doing `ps -e | grep -i pdf` yields 

` 3419 pts/2    00:00:00 PDFXCview
 3420 pts/2    00:00:02 PDFXCview.exe`

Please make sure you are using the pid of PDFXCview.exe and not the shell script (PDFXCview without .exe).

Comment: Thanks. Is there some way to get the child process pid from the script pid? @NonnyMoose

Comment: Yep! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743940/5937008)